# How to connect with database(mongodb in server 2) from docker container (running in server 1)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

Server 1->10.0.0.47
Server 2->10.0.1.202

All ports between these two servers are open as they are in same VPN in aws

version: '3.3'

```
networks:
 net:
    external: true
services:
  backend:
    image: test/test-backend:prod
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - discovery
```

ERROR:Connection refused
Note When i try to change the composer like below
connection with mongo established but unable to access the service on port 8000

```
networks:
 net:
    external: true
services:
  backend:
    image: test/test-backend:prod
    expose:
       - "27017:27017"
    ports:
       - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - discovery
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! You're going to need to add more information to your question for people to be able to help you: click "Edit" and add some more explanation about what's going on, what you've tried (the full configuration and how you're connecting would be useful!). Also, try to use the formatting features to make your code readable.

Comment: What host and port are you trying to connect to, from where (which host; in a container or not)?

Answer (score 0):

The Expose instruction does not change anything, it's for documentation only. You can read more about it in the [Dockerfile reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose).

If the 2 Server are in the same Docker network, you could change the mongoDB port to 8000 in its installation configuration. Then, you don't need to specify a port etc. in the docker-compose configuration.

If you want to access the mongoDB service from outside, you have to change the docker-compose configuration to:

```
ports:
   - "8000:27017"
```